# trap Spring context close error

Tags: spring, hbase, spring-data-hadoop

I have a spring Integration project using spring-hadoop.
I have an Hbase template as follows,

```
<beans:bean id="fsh" class="org.springframework.data.hadoop.fs.FsShell">
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="hbaseTemplate"  
   class="org.springframework.data.hadoop.hbase.HbaseTemplate">
    <beans:property name="configuration" ref="hdpConfiguration" />
</beans:bean>
```

Now, when I shutdown the app and the context at the end, it throws a strange error,

> o.a.h.hbase.client.HConnectionManager    : Connection not found in the list, can't delete it (connection key=HConnectionKey{properties={hbase.zookeeper.quorum=xxx.com,xxx.com, hbase.rpc.timeout=60000, hbase.client.prefetch.limit=10, hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort=2181, zookeeper.znode.parent=/hbase-secure, hbase.client.retries.number=35, hbase.client.pause=100}, username='xyz@PQR.COM'}). May be the key was modified?

As I understand, this was an innocuous error and was thrown even in Hadoop 1.x

I have migrated to Hadoop 2.x and Spring-Hadoop-2.0.4
But now, spring throws an Exception which earlier was not thrown,

> java.lang.Exception: null
>                   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.deleteConnection(HConnectionManager.java:488)
>                   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.deleteConnection(HConnectionManager.java:424)
>                   at org.springframework.data.hadoop.hbase.HbaseConfigurationFactoryBean.destroy(HbaseConfigurationFactoryBean.java:80)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:258)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:907)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:914)
>                   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
>                   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:884)
>                   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:804)
>   2015-01-22 14:58:20.168  INFO   --- [      Thread-11] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService
>   2015-01-22 14:58:20.170  INFO   --- [      Thread-11] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
>   2015-01-22 14:58:20.175  INFO   --- [       Thread-2] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

Question, how can I trap this error so that it's not shown to the user...

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: I created https://jira.spring.io/browse/SHDP-470 to track and investigate this.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to resolve the error, simply by setting delete-connection to false, (default is 'true')

```
<hbase-configuration configration-ref="hdpConfiguration" delete-connection="false"/>
```

Comment: Which configuration are you talk about?